# C program to copy a file using I/O re-direction

Tags: c, linux

Although it seems like a basic lab, it's been a while for using C and Linux. So the program need to read from standard input & echos back whatever it read to standard output and program terminate on EOF.

Hint or direction of where to start would be appreciated.

Size of input buffer ( char array ) would be 1024

Thanks :)

Comment: Hint: the take a look at the functions in `stdio.h`.  If you want a simple program that maybe isn't particularly efficient, you can do this one character at a time in less than 30 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is nothing wrong with **character-oriented** input for the task, given your problem statement of:

> Size of input buffer ( char array ) would be 1024

I would **hint** (suggest) **line-oriented** input using either `fgets` or `getline` instead. A very simple implementation would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXS 1024

int main (void)
{
    char line[MAXS] = {0};

    while (fgets (line, MAXS, stdin) != NULL)
        printf ("%s", line);    /* fgets & getline read '\n' into line */

    return 0;
}
```

You can adjust `MAXS` to accommodate your maximum buffer size. Compile and use as:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o fgetsminimal fgetsminimal.c
```

then

```
./fgetsminimal < some_text_file > new_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Some hints, `getchar()` and `putchar()` from stdio.h would be helpful. A while loop that checks for `EOF` and calls `putchar()` until it you reach it would also be help.

Hope this helps you get started :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the great things with Internet and open source is that you can find this kind of code easily.

Just look on the source code of cat for exemple, which is just an enhanced version of what you are trying to build.

Here is a possible implementation:
[**cat.c (opensource.apple.com)**](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-71/cat/cat.c)